# Sharing Memory Between Parent Process and Worker Threads Using Shared Object

Tags: multithreading, c++11

**Question**

Is a shared object a good way to communicate state information between a parent process and one or more worker threads? I was imagining either one of two ways to communicate progress of work done - for example - by a worker thread:

1. Variables passed by reference to the worker thread

`std::atomic<int> percentageProgress;
std::thread worker_thread(someFunctionCall, std::ref(percentageProgress));`

2. Object - with state variables as object members - passed by reference

`std::atomic<SharedStateObj> mySharedStateObj;
std::thread worker_thread(someFunctionCall, std::ref(mySharedStateObj));`

---

**Additional Thoughts:**

If I declare the SharedStateObj member variables as static and initialize the mySharedStateObj in the main process how will this change a mySharedStateObj_worker object that is initialized inside a worker thread?

---

Language: C++11
System: Nvidia Jetson
Operating System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: For inter-thread communication via variables, there are essentially two options: 1. [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) or 2. variables guarded with a [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex). [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) is not sufficient for this.

Comment: @Scheff apologies, I forgot to add std::atomic<int> to the integer, I Will put that in! Thank you

Comment: `std::atomic`s are cheaper than `mutex` guarded variables but only for types which are natively supported on the resp. platform. (If not, the implementation of `std::atomic` may fall back to `mutex` which is stated e.g. on [`std::atomic::is_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free).)

Comment: If you make `SharedStateObj` `static` and modifies (parts of) it in a thread, then you don't need to pass it as argument. However, you still need to make the modified parts `std::atomic` or guard any read/write access with a `std::mutex`. Otherwise, you have to expect sporadic errors or other strange effects.

Comment: @Scheff is it even worth having static members if I am going to pass the object by reference to the worker thread? Would it add any security or reliability to have each worker thread create its own instance and modify values from there, If I am going to wrap the access in a class and use std::mutex/std::atomic for write/read either way?

Comment: _each worker thread create its own instance_??? It's not like in multi-processing. One variable -> same variable/address in every thread. However, `atomic` or `mutex` are necessary to prevent/sync. potiential concurrent accesses which may otherwise bring a variable into an inconsistent state. Of course, you may have local variables in thread functions which are "thread private" and need not be safed. Additionally, there is the new storage class [`thread_local`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), but my premise was we are talking about inter-thread communication...

Comment: If you intend to pass variable by reference, it's not necessary to make it global or `static`. All you need to ensure is that it outlives the thread. Imagine, a function starts a thread, passing a reference to a local variable, and then returns before the thread is joined. That would be a counter-example (and leave the thread with a dangling reference).

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes a lot of sense. I was thinking about local scoping in main for example that isn't accessible to a worker-thread. It would have to be declared at global scope which doesn't seem like good practice. @Scheff